# Is there a way to compare a variable to each item in a list?

Tags: python

How do I compare a variable to each item in a list and return values that are less than the variable?

```
x = 150
my_list = [15, 100, 500, 2000, 5000]
```

So I want to return a list with 15 and 100.
I am trying something like the following for loop:

```
for n in my_list:
    if x > my_list[n]:
         print("True")
```

which gives me an index error. I understand why I'm getting the index error, what else can I try?

Comment: It should be `for n in range(len(my_list)):` or `if x > n:`

Comment: Why are you doing `my_list[n]`??? `n` is the *value in the list*, it isn't supposed to be an index. You just want `if x > n`

Comment: @Nick it never makes sense to use an index if you dont' actually need the index except for indexing into that specific index on each iteration. Just loop over the data directly

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga absolutely; I was just pointing out how OP could change their code to make it work, without any commentary as to the "correct" way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension:

```
x = 150
my_list = [15, 100, 500, 2000, 5000]

print ([ y for y in my_list if y < x ])
```

Output:

```
[15,100]
```

Answer (score 1):

When writing a for loop in Python like

```
for n in my_list:
    if x > my_list[n]:
         print("True")
```

`n` in each loop would be the item in the list itself rather than the index. for if you print all the `n`s out it will be `15, 100, 500, 2000, 5000` not `0, 1, 2, 3, 4`

So your code would be:

```
for n in my_list: # n is the number
    if x > n:
         print("True")
```

There are other ways you can get the index of the item instead. For example, using enumerate (see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: Replaced a link to w3schools with the official documentation. w3schools is a notoriously bad source of information, always prefer the official docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) and then convert it into the list if you need a list:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda n: x > n, my_list))
[15, 100]
```

Comment: Could use `x.__gt__` method reference instead of a lambda. But you also need to call `list` on the result to get a list - `filter` is lazy in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and here's the pandas way, which supports [logical indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) like you're asking for:

```
import pandas as pd

x = 150 
my_series = pd.Series([15, 100, 500, 2000, 5000])

my_series[my_series > x].tolist()
[500, 2000, 5000]

# Note that if we omitted the `.tolist()` call, we'd get a series with numerical indices, which you don't want
my_series[my_series > x]
2     500
3    2000
4    5000
dtype: int64
```

If you're going to be doing any non-trivial data work, esp. with multiple columns or tables, recommend you start using pandas, it has a rich set of predefined methods for DataFrame and Series. Base python is very very limited and will quickly drive you nuts.

Answer (score 0):

[Cheukting's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67013500/12975140) already explains how for loops work in Python. In order to make your new list, first create it as an empty list, and then add the appropriate numbers to it in the for loop.

```py
x = 150
my_list = [15, 100, 500, 2000, 5000]

less_than_x = []
for num in my_list:
    if num < x:
        less_than_x.append(num)
```

This could also be accomplished with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
less_than_x = [num for num in my_list if num < x]
```